# How to join with ColumnA = (ColumnB - 1)

Tags: r

I am trying to join two dataframe. The condition of the join is not ColumnA=ColumnB but ColumnA=ColumnB*Function.
With the function merge, I dont see how i can handle it

There a exemple,

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c(5,4,3,2), CASE=c("A","B","C","D"))
df2 <- data.frame(ID=c(6,5,4,3), RESULT=c("ResultA","ResultB","ResultC","ResultD"))
```

I would like to join df1 and df2 with somethng like **df1$ID = df2$ID - 1**, to have the result:

```
df_result<- data.frame(ID_df1=c(5,4,3,2), CASE=c("A","B","C","D"), RESULT=c("Result5","Result4","Result3","Result2"))
```

I have tried to delete the quotation marks in the join, but it does not work:

```
df_result <- merge ( x = df1, y = df2, by.x = ID , by.y = ID - 1 , all.x = TRUE)
```

Could some one helps me? : )

Thank you !

Comment: I'm not at my computer so can't check to figure out if there is a way to do it directly with merge. But you could always make a new column that is ID-1 in df2 and merge on that.

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your quick reply. In fact I simplied my issue with a simple exemple. Actually, i would like to use fonction with multiple conditions. Like: df1$date=df2$date , if no result then df1$date=df2$date-2 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution to reproduce your expected output would be

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(df1, df2 %>% mutate(ID = ID - 1)) %>%
    mutate(RESULT = str_replace(RESULT, "^(.+)[A-Z]$", paste0("\\1", ID)))
#Joining, by = "ID"
#  ID CASE  RESULT
#1  5    A Result5
#2  4    B Result4
#3  3    C Result3
#4  2    D Result2
```

Explanation: If you only want to merge by `ID` and `ID - 1` a simple

```
left_join(df1, df2 %>% mutate(ID = ID - 1))
#  ID CASE  RESULT
#1  5    A ResultA
#2  4    B ResultB
#3  3    C ResultC
#4  2    D ResultD
```

is sufficient. The additional `mutate` takes care of renaming `RESULT` according to your expected output.

---

Or a base R option would start from

```
merge(df1, transform(df2, ID = ID - 1), by = "ID")
#  ID CASE  RESULT
#1  2    D ResultD
#2  3    C ResultC
#3  4    B ResultB
#4  5    A ResultA
```

and including renaming `RESULT`

```
transform(
    merge(df1, transform(df2, ID = ID - 1), by = "ID"),
    RESULT = paste0(substr(RESULT, 1, nchar(as.character(RESULT)) - 1), ID))
#  ID CASE  RESULT
#1  2    D Result2
#2  3    C Result3
#3  4    B Result4
#4  5    A Result5
```

reproducing your expected output (with a slightly different row ordering).

Answer (score 0):

Such a join is easy to do with SQL.  In this case every row of `df1` has a match in `df2` so we could omit the `left` keyword but if there were rows in `df1` with no match in `df2` the `left` would ensure that they are retained.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select 
    a.*, 
    substr(b.RESULT, 1, length(b.RESULT)-1) || cast(a.ID as integer) as RESULT
  from df1 as a 
  left join df2 as b on a.id = b.id - 1")
```

The `on` clause can have complex conditions connected with `and` and/or `or` in case you need more complicated conditions.

Alternately do the join in SQL and then the transformation of `RESULT` separately.

```
s <- sqldf("select a.*, b.RESULT
  from df1 as a 
  left join df2 as b on a.id = b.id - 1")
transform(s, RESULT = paste0(sub(".$", "", RESULT), ID))
```

Comment: Thanks ! It can be usefull if I want to connect with the condition "Or"